# Installing windows OS on ISCSI sever or san storage using IPXE BOOT

Tags: iscsi, san, ipxe

[image]

Hi good people,

I'm trying to make a diskless PC client and install the operating system on a SAN Storage. As of now i'm using windows server 2012 R2 and it will serve as my DHCP/WDS and SAN server. So I found a video from yourtube on **"Bjørn Jentoft"** channel with the title **"Hyper-V: Windows installation to ISCSI disk"** I followed all the steps and configurations but it didn't quit work for me. But I keep repeating his video to look if I miss something on the configuration steps, but when I checked everything it appears that I didn't miss anything based on what he showed on the video tutorial. By the way he used HYPER-V on his tutorial and I'm using physical machines.

Thank you.

Comment: Try asking this on serverfault.com - it's dedicated to professional server and networking advice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: You are trying to download client1.txt from tftp / what tid you actually put into your DHCP config, and why?